# Java 8 stream through multiple layers and concatenate all items at the bottom-most layer

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I currently have a multiple layer structure data that is like this:

> Industry class has a private field `Set<Company>` that can be null.
>
> Company class has a private field `Set<Division>` that can be null.
>
> Division class has a private field `Set<Group>` that can be null.
>
> Group class has a private field `groupName` that can be null and is
>   retrievable with a getter (`getGroupName()`).

I am trying to stream an instance of Industry all way down to the Group layer and concatenate all the groupName's into one String with "/" in between.

If the this instance of Industry doesn't contain any groupName, return the string "null".

Based on my limited knowledge of Java 8, I am thinking of coding like this:

```
industry.stream()
     .flatmap(industry -> industry.getCompanies().stream())
     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
     .flatmap(company -> company.getDivisions().stream())
     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
     .flatmap(division -> division.getGroups().stream())
     .map(group -> group.getGroupName)
     .collect(Collectors.joining("/")));
```

This code seems to flawed in someway.  Also, I am not sure where to add the statement that if Industry cannot retrieve any groupName, rather than concatenate all groupName into one string simply return a string "null".

What is the proper way to use Java 8 stream in my situation?

Thanks.

Comment: What if only some group names are `null`?

Comment: @Holger In that case, we still want to concatenate the ones that are not null.  Only in the extreme case of all group names are null, do we want the string "null".  Thanks.

Comment: @Aominè I think your suggestion is close, but I want only non null groupNames to be concatenated.  So the final result is either a string that is concatenated with valid values of groupName or the string "null" in the extreme case of all group names are null.  Thanks.

Comment: What makes you say the code "*seems to be flawed in some way*"?

Comment: Does your `Industry` class have a `stream()` method that returns `Stream<Industry>`? It sounds like you should start from `industry.getCompanies().stream()` instead.

Comment: Other than the fact the your null checks are too late, it looks basically correct to me.

Comment: When you say "has a private field `...` that can be null" do you mean "has a private field `...` that is never null but may contain nulls"? Your code sample suggests that's what you meant. Otherwise, you should either make those fields non-null (use empty sets) or else your code needs to use empty streams for null fields instead of calling `.stream()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Collectors.joining(…)` is based on the class `StringJoiner`. It offers its delimiter, prefix, and suffix features, but unfortunately not the ability to provide the empty value.

To add that feature, we’ll have to re-implement `Collectors.joining`, which thankfully is not so hard when using `StringJoiner`.

Change the last line of your stream operation

```
.collect(Collectors.joining("/"));
```

to

```
.filter(Objects::nonNull) // elide all null elements
.collect(()->new StringJoiner("/", "", "").setEmptyValue("null"), // use "null" when empty
         StringJoiner::add, StringJoiner::merge).toString();
```

Comment: This solution works exactly as I hoped.  The example is also clear.  Thanks.

Comment: You may prefer to generalize this into a reusable `Collector` implementation by using a static factory method (`MyCollectors.joiningOrEmptyValue("/", "", "", "null")`) that calls `Collector.of(...)`. See [question 56560842](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56560842/custom-collector-to-join-stream-on-delimiter-suffix-and-prefix-only-if-stream-i).

Comment: @AndrewF just as I said in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56560842/custom-collector-to-join-stream-on-delimiter-suffix-and-prefix-only-if-stream-i#comment99711235_56560952), “*The best choice would be creating a factory method similar to the methods in `Collectors`, i.e. a `joining` with four parameters.*”

Comment: @Holger I am glad you agree. That answer and its comments are the reasons that I linked to that question. But implementing a static factory method that calls `Collector.of(...)` is more convenient than trying to match the approach of the `Collectors` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I understood your question as pretty much anything can be null. In this case you could create your own function to deal with this. I made one as such:

```
/**
 * Creates a stream function for the provided collection function which ignores all null values.
 * Will filter out null values passed into the collection function and null values from the resulting stream
 * @param collectionFn
 * @param <T>
 * @param <R>
 * @return
 */
public static <T, R> Function<T, Stream<R>> nullSafeMapper(Function<T, Collection<R>> collectionFn) {
    return (v) -> Optional.ofNullable(v)
            .map(collectionFn)
            .map(Collection::stream)
            .orElse(Stream.empty())
            .filter(Objects::nonNull);
}
```

Basically its completely null safe, filtering out anything which is null in the input and output. and could be used as such:

```
industries.stream()
    .flatMap(SO46101593.nullSafeMapper(Industry::getCompanies))
    .flatMap(SO46101593.nullSafeMapper(Company::getDivisions))
    .flatMap(SO46101593.nullSafeMapper(Division::getGroups))
    .map(group -> group.getGroupName())
    .filter(Objects::nonNull) // filter out null group names
    .collect(Collectors.joining("/"));
```

You could also take that logic and push it down directly into your expression but since it has to be repeated 3 times it gets a bit... verbose and repetitive

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with null checks:

```
String s = industries.stream()
.filter( i -> i.getCompanies() != null ).flatMap( i -> i.getCompanies().stream() )
    .filter( c -> c != null && c.getDivisions() != null ).flatMap( c -> c.getDivisions().stream() )
        .filter( d -> d != null && d.getGroups() != null ).flatMap( d -> d.getGroups().stream() )
            .filter( g -> g != null && g.getGroupName() != null ).map( g -> g.getGroupName() )                    
.collect( Collectors.joining("/") );
```

You can replace `Collectors.joining("/")` with Holger's example.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Stream.of(industry)
        .map(Industry::getCompanies).filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .map(Company::getDivisions).filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .map(Division::getGroups).filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .map(Group::getGroupName).filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.joining("/"),
                names -> names.isEmpty() ? "null" : names));
```

I'm assuming `industry.stream()` is incorrect, since you say you're working from "an instance of Industry". Instead, I make a `Stream<Industry>` with one element.

You need to do the null checks on the sets before you try to call `stream` on them. You're checking whether `stream` returns null, which is too late.

The final transform from empty result to "null" falls under the concept of the "finisher" function in `Collector`. `Collectors.joining` doesn't let you specify a finisher directly, but you can use `Collectors.collectingAndThen` to add a finisher to any existing `Collector`.