# Perform actions with streaming api before/after foreach

Tags: java, foreach, java-stream

Here's the non-stream code that I want to reproduce using *only* the streaming api if possible:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four");
list.removeIf(s -> s.length() <= 3);

if (!list.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("before");
    for (String elem : list) {
        System.out.println(elem);
    }
    System.out.println("after");
}
```

Of course simple iteration is easy with a stream:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four");
list.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.length() > 3)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

But I need to add the "before" and "after" lines only if the stream is not empty after filtering. Is this possible in one statement or do I need to `collect`?

This hardly seems like a better solution...

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four");
List<String> filtered = list.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.length() > 3)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
if (!filtered.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("before");
    filtered.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("after");
}
```

**Update:** The examples above with Strings are too simple. I actually need to write a json array if the filtered list is not empty. I cannot write an empty array.

```
private void writeJsonArray(JsonGenerator g, List<String> list) {
    list.removeIf(s -> s.length() <= 3);
    
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        g.writeArrayFieldStart("arr");
        for (String elem : list) {
            g.writeString(elem);
        }
        g.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Iterator<String> it = list.stream() .filter(s -> s.length() > 3) .iterator(); if(it.hasNext()) { g.writeArrayFieldStart("arr"); it.forEachRemaining(g::writeString); g.writeEndArray();}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `anyMatch()` and `Collectors.joining()` with prefix and suffix:

```
private static String NEW_LINE = System.lineSeparator();

public static void print(List<String> list) {
    String str = list.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.length() > 3) 
        ? list.stream().filter(s -> s.length() > 3)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(NEW_LINE, 
                        "before" + NEW_LINE, NEW_LINE + "after"))
        : "";
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

As an alternative approach, you can reduce the `stream` using `StringBuilder` as identity. Then, if the `StringBuilder` isn't empty, you can insert `"before"` and append `"after"`. This approach performs only one terminal operation.

```
public static void print(List<String> list) {
    StringBuilder sb = list.stream()
            .filter(str -> str.length() > 3)
            .reduce(new StringBuilder(), 
                    (s, str) -> s.append(str).append(NEW_LINE), 
                    StringBuilder::append);
    if (!sb.isEmpty()) {
        sb.insert(0, NEW_LINE).insert(0, "before")
            .append("after");
    }
    
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Test:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four");

print(list);
```

Output:

```
before
three
four
after
```

Comment: Thanks for the working solution. However, I may have made my example too simple. In my real-life scenario, I need to call `JsonGenerator#writeArrayFieldStart(String)` before, `JsonGenerator#writeEndArray()` after and `JsonGenerator#writeString(String)` for each element in the List. The solution shouldn't return anything. I'll update my question.

Comment: @Matt That's a totally different question (and for a different reason). The method `JsonGenerator.writeString(String)` throws a checked exception `IOException`, however `streams` don't allow throwing checked exceptions. If you post a new queston for that specific issue, I'll try to tackle it there.

Comment: `Collectors.joining` uses `StringJoiner`. By decomposing the collector logic, you can get to [a solution handling empty case without iterating twice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46101849/2711488).

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Stream.concat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat(java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.stream.Stream)) for this:

```
Stream.concat(
    Stream.of("before"),
    Stream.concat(
        list.stream().filter(s -> s.length() > 3),
        Stream.of("after")))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

You might find it more readable split the logic into separate statements:

```
Stream<String> stream = list.stream().filter(s -> s.length() > 3);
stream = Stream.concat(Stream.of("before"), stream);
stream = Stream.concat(stream, Stream.of("after"));
stream.forEach(System.out::println);
```